# Hide past items based on date inside foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a custom component that displays "coming soon" items based on dates. I am trying to hide all those items that are past today's date. However if there is no future items it does not display the custom text.

How do I do it inside a foreach loop? Or how can I insert php break? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if($item->state ==1 && strtotime($item->event_date) > strtotime(JFactory::getDate())): ?>
        <div class="cont">
            <!-- Display values from DB -->
        </div>
    <?php elseif($item->state ==1 && strtotime($item->event_date) < strtotime(JFactory::getDate())): ?>
        <!-- Dont display anything -->
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="cont">
            <!-- Display custom text -->
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the "else" section outside of the foreach loop, since if there are no items, the foreach loop never runs:

```
<?php $item_displayed = false; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
    <?php if($item->state ==1 && strtotime($item->event_date) > strtotime(JFactory::getDate())): ?>
        <?php $item_displayed = true; ?>
        <div class="cont">
            <!-- Display values from DB -->
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if (!$item_displayed) : ?>
    <div class="cont">
        <!-- Display custom text -->
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, I added a variable that states that an item has not been displayed. If any item in the loop is displayed, I then switch that variable to true. After the loop I will then display the custom text if there was no items or if no item is upcoming.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and also the explanation. It worked like a charm!